# How visible property of library component comment/designator working?

Tags: altium-designer

If I uncheck "visible" of comment/designator in library component they still appeares when I put them on schematic. I can uncheck visible in schematic too but can this manage on library level?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe should work. If you uncheck the visible check-box and save the library, the designator should not appear when you drag the component from the library into the schematic.

If you want to hide the designator for components in the entire library or the entire schematic I would use an iterator in a Script. Something like this:

```
    For I := 0 to Project.DM_LogicalDocumentCount - 1 Do
       Begin
           Doc := Project.DM_LogicalDocuments(I);

           If Doc.DM_DocumentKind = 'SCHLIB' Then
           Begin
           CurrentLib := SchServer.GetSchDocumentByPath(Doc.DM_FullPath);

           LibraryIterator := CurrentLib.SchLibIterator_Create;
           LibraryIterator.AddFilter_ObjectSet(MkSet(eSchComponent));
               Try

                  LibComp := LibraryIterator.FirstSchObject;
                  While LibComp <> Nil Do
                  Begin
                        //Change the LibComp parameters here

                        LibComp := LibraryIterator.NextSchObject;
                  End;
               Finally
                  CurrentLib.SchIterator_Destroy(LibraryIterator);
               End;
           End;
       End;
```